# How can I retrieve the device information?

Tags: powershell, windows, devices

From *Windows Server 2012 R2*, how can I retrieve a device's vendor name and model number without physically opening the machine?  For instance, PCI cards.

`Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity` returns a bunch of information, including the manufacturer and the name, but not the actual model.

Same thing with `Device Manager`.

Comment: Can someone explain what is wrong with the questions that got these down votes? If it is that easy, why isn't anybody answering it?

Comment: I edited your question to help with clarity.

Comment: BTW, I think that's about as close as you're going to get with built in PS commands and no 3rd party utilities, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You may need to look at each individual device installed.

Comment: @Davidw What do you mean by "look at each individual device"?

Comment: There are a number of WMI classes for specific devices, you might try those.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the hardware has the manufacturer's advertising model number anywhere on it. Windows can see what microchips it's talking to, and it can read firmware values, but if the hardware is sold to lots of vendors and rebranded, the information on the hardware doesn't necessarily have anything matching the model number on the box.

Answer (score -3):

Did you try `msinfo32.exe`?

Maybe third part software could show it like Lansweeper or aida64.

Comment: Same issue: basic information which does not include the model number.